# Example of a non-complete coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The most common coordinate systems to represent space are cartesian, spherical and cylindrical. These are all complete, meaning that they can represent any point in space. What is an example of a coordinate system $[u_1,u_2,u_3]$ such that it is not complete ( it leaves gaps ) ?

Comment: What is your definition of a coordinate system? By definition it should describe any point.

Comment: I have never seen such a thing, although it could be artificially built. SImply consider any non-onto map $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$

Comment: What about letting $(x,y)$ represent the point $(e^x, e^y)$? Then the coordinates $(x,y)$ will be able to describe exactly the top right quadrant of the plane.